# How to properly get svg styles and append to Raphael?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I have a svg file and use Raphael library. My svg file contain the following styles:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil1 {fill:#2B2A29}
    .fil0 {fill:#009846;fill-opacity:1}
    .fnt0 {font-weight:bold;font-size:10.9996;font-family:'Arial'}
   ]]>
  </style>
  <filter id="Filter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="660" height="400">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
    <feOffset in="blur" dx="0" dy="3" result="offsetBlur"/>
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="offsetBlur"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
 </defs>
```

For convert this svg file to `Raphael` I using [this](http://readysetraphael.com/) online tool.  This tools not insert my style. And I get the following markup:

```
<svg height="400" version="1.1" width="660" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc>Created with RaphaГ«l 2.1.0</desc><defs/><path style="stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M296,116L297,118L343,124L375,105L366,94L339,88L320,98L319,98Z" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1"/>
```

...

As you can see the `defs` tag is empty.

I have tryed manually add styles:

```
$('defs').append('<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[.fil1 {fill:#2B2A29}.fil0 {fill:#009846;fill-opacity:1}.fnt0 {font-weight:bold;font-size:10.9996;font-family:'Arial'}]]></style><filter id="Filter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="660" height="400"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/><feOffset in="blur" dx="0" dy="3" result="offsetBlur"/><feMerge><feMergeNode in="offsetBlur"/><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge></filter>');
```

But, I get error:

```
missing ) after argument list

...ght:bold;font-size:10.9996;font-family:'Arial'}]]></style><filter id="Filter" fi...
```

How to properly get svg styles and append with `Raphael`?

Comment: `font-family:'Arial'` to `font-family:"Arial"`

Comment: Just note that if you style the nodes by just appending the style element it's probably not going to work properly in older IE versions, most likely you will have to use the raphaël API to set the fill/font-family/etc as attributes instead.